# Unity Jump function issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on this script for the past day. For some reason my character will not jump as long as it's animator is active. I've got into the animation (there is only one) and removed all references to the animation placing a position anywhere and still the issue presides.

I have discovered that I can make my player jump if I use Co-routine which I'm using. However, I'm still new to using them and I can't work out why my player won't fall to the ground once a force has been added to it. And my player only moves up when the button is clicked. Could someone please take a look at my script and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public float jumpSpeed = 100.0f;
public float jumpHeight = 2.0f;
public AudioClip jumpSound;

private GameObject pos;
private bool moving;
private bool isJumping;

void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))// && !moving)
    {
        isJumping = true;
        StartCoroutine(JumpPlayer(gameObject.transform.localPosition));
    }
    else
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }
}

IEnumerator JumpPlayer(Vector3 startPos)
{
    Vector3 jump = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, jumpHeight, transform.localPosition.z);

    float t = 0f;

    t += Time.deltaTime / jumpSpeed;
    rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpSpeed);
    //gameObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, jump, 0.5f);
    //isJumping = false;
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: There was similar (or near) question and the answer was to use `Impulse` for `AddForce`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your use of coroutine isn't doing anything in particular - because it only does `yield return null` at the end, it'll run in a single frame and then exit. You could make it a regular `void` function and you shouldn't see any change in behaviour.

Removing other redundant code and you have just this:

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpSpeed);
}
```

This force is added for only a single frame: the frame where the mouse button is pressed down (if you used `Input.GetMouseButton` instead, you'd see the force applied for multiple frames).

You say "my player only moves up when the button is clicked" but I'm not clear why that's a problem - perhaps you mean that the player should continue to move up for as long as the button is held, in which case you should refer to my previous paragraph.

The most obvious reasons for the player not falling again are related to the `RigidBody` component: do you have weight & drag set to suitable values? An easy way to test this would be to position your player some distance from the ground at the start of the scene, and ensure that they fall to the ground when you start the scene.

Another reason might be that you're using the default override of `.AddForce` in an `Update` cycle. The default behaviour of this method applies force during the `FixedUpdate` calls, and you might find that using `ForceMode.Impulse` or `ForceMode.VelocityChange` gives you the result you're looking for.